# Thread Options is it possible to do (if there is no message in the textbox the button is disabled?

Tags: c#

soo yea title says it all i wanna know how to do it and the language is c#

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        string x;
        x = textBox1.Text;
        if (x != "")
        {
            some code...
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please type something");
        }
```

.
.
.//

but it only works if it was empty but if you type "   " (space) it works fine thats the poblem...
Thanks!

Comment: because `" " != ""` Have you tried methods like `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Comment: `soo yea title says it all i wanna know` BTW: Your title doesn't mean anything to me. Have you just selected random words from dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Use the .trim() method on the string object

```
if (!x.trim().Equals(""))
```

That will account for whitespace.
[String.Trim() reference.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This would do the job.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string x;
    x = textBox1.Text;
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
    {
        some code...
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please type something");
    }
}
```

FYI:  Saying title says it all is not a good way to ask question. And in this case Threading is not really involve in your question.
If you are in wpf DataBinding can be done with the  Command property on button in order to avoid these message box. Then again it depends on the context of your app.

Comment: Finallyyyyyyyyy it worked thank you so much :* and sorry for the way i asked ^^

Comment: @Beyondstrike if you got your answer, you may also want to read this to know what to do next http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work This may be a a start for learning the rules of SO.